# Adding PatternMatchListener to Eclipse Console in which stage of View Lifecycle

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am developing an Eclipse plug-in which will be triggered by a specific pattern string found (e.g., stack trace) in the default console opened in Eclipse and will show some notification in a custom view. I know how add the listener to the available consoles.But I am not sure in which phase of Eclipse View life cycle I need to add the listener. Currently I am adding in createPartControl which is not what I want, because it forces to me to open the view manually to perform the binding the listener with the consoles.

```
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    //got the default console from ConsolePlugin
    TextConsole tconsole=(TextConsole)defaultConsole;
    tconsole.addPatternMatchListener(new IPatternMatchListener() {
       // implementation codes goes here
   }
```

}

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: No answer yet? Can I do anything to make the requirements clearer?

Comment: start(BundleContext context) in Avtivator class is the best choice as it solves the problem.